# After Fedora 30 update MYSQL won't start

Tags: mysql, fedora

After upgrading to fedora 30 I try to start MySQL and it keeps saying that libcrypt.so.1 can't be found

I've loaded the latest MySQL community version (8.x), which disn't fix anything, and loaded the latest libxcrypt-compat-4.4.6-1.fc30.i686 (which also hasn't changed anything), and rebooted just to be sure.

Is there a way to get the libcrypt.so.1 library or a way to start MYSQL without it?

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 30 is now using libcrypt.so.2 by default. If you need the older version you can install it, it's just not included by default.

```
sudo dnf install libxcrypt-compat
```

Comment: Can you add some context around your answer?